# Posting a web form to a different page in asp.net 3.5

Tags: .net-3.5, form-submit

I am told that form.action attribute is being honored right now; so we can post a form to a different page. i have tried that, but i get an error to do with ViewState (I realise why).

What I am trying to find out for sure if I can in fact post to a different page w/o getting this error; otherwise I see no point for Microsoft to implement this "feature" at all,

Unfortunately, in my app i HAVE to post to a different IP, so I have to make this work. Any ideas?

I am completely baffled as to why honor form.action but not make it work - it's a soft of a half-baked feature. According to MS this is a known issue.

Refer to this:
[here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970459)

Comment: To whoever voted to close it, could you please solve this issue for me? 
I would really appreciate your input as you seem to think that my question is redundant, please share your expertise and knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So if your machine keys are the same and or you post without viewstate on the page, then you can cross post all day long.

So if you set the machine key in the machine config of both servers to the same value you should be good.

Comment: can two machines have the same machine key? (we have two servers and I need to be able to crosspost).

how do I generate machine key?

Comment: Chris, I am posting for now from one page to another IN THE SAME APPLICATION on the SAME machine (my dev machine).
what gives? this makes no sense to me, am i missing something?

Comment: oh and I need viewstate. if i can't use viewstate, this solution is useless for me. 

is it possible to cross post or not? if so, what do i need to do to achieve error-less cross posting with viewstate enabled?